# VBA tabulation based on lookup

Tags: vba, reference, lookup, tabulate

**tl;dr?** I need to tabulate hours from one sheet and write the value in the cell on another sheet.

**Here are the relevant details:**
I need help calculating a sum that is based on a set of referenced values in an Excel workbook. We're trying to evenly distribute the things that need to be done around the office according to an average expected time commitment and we have a high turnover rate on employees. When folks leave, others pick up the slack, and when new folks come in, we redistribute. So we need the summed numbers to be dynamic.

I have a list of jobs for our employees in a sheet named "Raw List", a named array ("Names") with their last names in the "Member List" sheet, and this snazzy table on the "Job Matrix" sheet. Job Matrix basically takes a three column sheet (job name, primary dude, backup dude) and converts it to a multi column sheet (job name, employee 1, employee 2, etc. to employee 9) so we can see the full scope of what everyone has on their plate.

In order to populate this "Job Matrix" table, I have working lookup commands that individually check each cell on the matrix against the same row on the raw list. If the person's name at the top is listed in the 'primary' or 'backup' column, a "P" or "B" is added to the cell accordingly. I then count all the "P"s and "B"s at the bottom. But this list of tasks assigned isn't weighted for how long they actually take.

So... for that very last 'weight average' row, I'm trying to iterate through each name and calculate a total. "Hi" time commitments are 3 "points", "Med" are 2, "Low" are 1. I know *what* I want to do, just not quite *how*. Super rusty on the lookup commands.

Here is the pseudocode I think I need to apply. The clincher? I need to try to do this without macros, even if it's one giant pile of code in each cell. Our admin has macro files looked down (le sigh), so if I can do this in a regular .xlsx workbook, that'd be the best case scenario.

```
'pseudocode follows:

for each member in the the named array "Names" (on sheet "Employee List"):
    for each row on the "Raw List" sheet, find the current member's name in col b or c
        if found, look in column e on that same row
            if value is "Hi", add 3 to a running tally
            if value is "Med", add 2 to a running tally
            if value is "Low", add 1 to a running tally
        on the "Job Matrix" sheet (row 39, col w/ mbr's name) print running tally for that member
        reset value of running tally to 0
    next row
next member
```

Hope that helps! If you guys know how/where I can attach a file (or send it to a pastebin site and then link to that here), I'm all ears.

Comment: Hi Nate, on StackOverflow, we like to keep the questions as objective as possible, as if it's an encyclopedia, so unnecesary words (like "hello", "help me", "thanks" and offtopic talk) is usually trimmed down to keep the focus on the question. I hope that answers the confusion.